# An interesting setting in statistical causal inference

Tags: statistics, system-identification, causality

I'm writing a research paper and considering the following settings:

There are three discrete variables which construct a simple causal graph: Treatment **T**, outcome **Y**, and confounders **U**. Here we have the classical causal path {T, U}->Y, U-> T.

We consider the following setting: We only have **the marginal distribution of confounder P(U) and the joint distribution of observations P(X, Y)**. Then we're interested in some causal effect quantities, i.e., the interventional probability.

**My question is**: Could we show some realistic examples perfectly satisfying the above setting instead of some semi-synthetic examples? Some scenarios, like privacy protection, would be relevant.

I sincerely have no other idea and really appreciate your help!!~~I **promise** I will add your name warmly to the acknowledgement (even as a co-author).